# Slide Effect Not Working

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created a carousel with unlimited swipe option. If user swipe left from last item, the first item will be appeared and if swipe right from first item, the last item will be appeared. Slide effect is working for every swipe event, but slide effect is not working while swiping from last item to first item and swiping from first item to last item. Here is my code-

```
categorizedCarousel = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
        title: record.data.name,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        listeners: {
            element: 'element',
            swipe: function(e) {
                if (e.direction == 'right') {

                    if (this.getActiveIndex() === 0) {
                        this.animateActiveItem(this.getMaxItemIndex(), {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
                    }
                } else {

                    if (this.getActiveIndex() === this.getMaxItemIndex()) {
                        this.animateActiveItem(0, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The above "{type: 'slide', direction: 'right/left'}" isn't working though. I am trying to find this solution for a long time, more than 2 weeks, but still no solution. Any solutin polease?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: With your html, css, etc...

Comment: [Here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/) you can create a sencha touch fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't actually have the images in the correct order in the dom to be able to display this slide animation.
For example:

```
<li>img 1</li>
<li>img 2</li>
<li>img 3</li>
<li>img 4</li>
```

if you want to swipe from img 4 to img1, you'd first have to place img 1 AFTER img 4 in the dom, so that they sit nicely next to each other - you can do this by either keep moving every item around or just have a clone of the first and last items at the beginning and end and once the animation is done, jump back to the actual item:

before sipe from 4 to 1:

```
<li>img 4 clone</li>
<li>img 1</li>
<li>img 2</li>
<li>img 3</li>
<li active>img 4</li>
<li>img 1 copy</li>
```

while animating:

```
<li>img 4 clone</li>
<li>img 1</li>
<li>img 2</li>
<li>img 3</li>
<li>img 4</li>
<li active>img 1 copy</li>
```

on animation done (jump to actual img 1)

```
<li>img 4 clone</li>
<li active>img 1</li>
<li>img 2</li>
<li>img 3</li>
<li>img 4</li>
<li>img 1 copy</li>
```

Comment: Please read my question first. My problem is not to go from last to first or first to last, my question is during those 2 slide, slide effect is not working....

Comment: That's what I am saying - the slide won't work because it tries to move two images at the same time - however those two images aren't next to each other so this isn't possible. In order to have them move together you'll have to fake the *next* image. If you could post your complete code in a fiddle it would probably help to explain.

Comment: if i fake them how about going to 2 after going from 4 then 1 or going to 3 from 1 then 2...

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why your implementation does not work (or might never work):

- Events for item rotating in `Ext.Carousel` are `dragstart` and `dragend`, not `swipe`. They are totally different in nature.
- `animateActiveItem` is not a proper action to animate between items in a carousel.
- You can not "preview" the first item when you "drag" from right to left to the last item because it's not there.

Here is a working override of `Ext.Carousel`. It does exactly what you want. Basically its idea is to "rotate" the `items` config of the carousel then force it to be refreshed.

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.InfCarousel',{
  xtype: 'InfCarousel',
  extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',

  rotateItemBack: function(item){
    if(!item) return null;
    var initem = item.items;
    var numitems = initem.length;
    var newItem = [];

    newItem.push(initem[numitems-1]);
    for(i=0; i<numitems-1; ++i)
      newItem.push(initem[i]);

    return newItem;
  },

  rotateItemFront: function(item){
    if(!item) return null;
    var initem = item.items;
    var numitems = initem.length;
    var newItem = [];

    for(i=0; i<numitems-1; ++i)
      newItem.push(initem[i+1]);

    newItem.push(initem[0]);

    return newItem;
  },

  config:{
    indicator: false,
    listeners:{
        activeitemchange:function(){
            this.fireEvent('activeitemchangeloop', arguments);
        },

        activeitemchangeloop: function ()
        {
          var activeIndex = this.getActiveIndex(),
              maxIndex = this.getMaxItemIndex();

          if(activeIndex == 0)
          {
              var items = this.getItems();

              var newItems = this.rotateItemBack(items);
              this.removeAll(false, false);
              this.add(newItems);

              this.setActiveItem(1);
              this.refresh();
          }

          else if(activeIndex == maxIndex)
          {
              var items = this.getItems();

              var newItems = this.rotateItemFront(items);
              this.removeAll(false, false);
              this.add(newItems);

              this.setActiveItem(maxIndex-1);
              this.refresh();
          }      
        }
    }
  }

});
```

**Note: if you still want to implement one on your own, you should definitely look at the source code of `Ext.Carousel`**, here: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/Carousel.html#Ext-carousel-Carousel (take a deeper look at `next` and `previous` method)

Comment: Please read my question first. My problem is not to go from last to first or first to last, my question is during those 2 slide, slide effect is not working....

Comment: @rafi: Also please know that `swipe` is not a good event to listen to in this situation. Actually `Ext.Carousel` uses `dragstart` and `dragend` events which are essentially different from `swipe` gesture.

Comment: Yes i have seen the dragstart/end events and i tried to use those but couldn't. Also i tried to create senchafiddle, but it is very hard to create one. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I have just updated my answer with more explanations, please have a deeper look at it